# How many characters 2 bytes can hold?

Tags: javascript, c++, vb.net

If I say 2 bytes can hold 510 characters of data will I be wrong? based on the fact that 1 byte can hold 0-255 max character

Comment: I'd say you're wrong. 1 byte size of 8 bits can hold a single 8 bit character, hence 2 bytes can hold two 8 bit characters. If you mean numbers, with two bytes the range is 0 - 65535.

Answer (score 6):

*One byte is* :

- 8 bits, each one can be either 0 or 1
- something that can represent 256 distinct values

*Two bytes are ..two bytes*.

- 16 bits
- something that can represent 65536 distinct values

There is no meaning in what a byte (or two bytes) ***is***, if you don't know the `encoding` used, what each single one of the 256 (or 65536) values are supposed to be/mean.

If you're talking about `Char`, you can't either say it's one or two or fifty chars...

`ASCII encoding` holds 128 distinct characters (95 chars can be displayed while the remaining are control chars) ranging from code 0 to 127 (Byte value expressed in decimal literal)

`Unicode encoding` (v7) is a generic encoding. You have the UTF-8, the UTF-16 Little Endian or Big Endian, and the UTF-32 Little Endian or Big Endian.

- UTF-8 requires either 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes to represent one single character.
- UTF-16 is a fixed-size character encoding : each char requires 2 bytes.
- UTF-32 is also a fixed size character encoding that requires 4 bytes per character.

There are hundreds of different Encodings that can represent one character for each of the 256 unique values a single Byte can represent. Like `ANSI`.

---

So I tend to say, yes, **you're wrong** thinking two bytes can hold 510 characters of data, assuming you're using one of the above encoding or similar.

But again, a Byte is a Byte, not a Char !

Let's imagine a (new) custom encoding with specific parser and formatter where each bit `[0 or 1]` define the selection of one word/text/string stored in a dictionary, and following words/text/string selection depends on the previous selected word (previous bit value)

The purpose of such type of encoding is somewhat useless, but hey ! Because you used a dictionary, you can affirm one single byte ***can*** represent exactly 510 characters of data (or even more) because of the use of this specific encoding/decoding..!

*Again, a byte is a byte, saying it holds one, two, zero or 510 characters doesn't mean anything **if you don't define first what is the encoding used***.

---

**EDIT !**

And while it's out of the scope of the question, `compression` is even more evil - and generally uses dictionary ;) - But compression are only effective from a *certain* amount of bytes....

Answer (score 1):

A character is a graphical representation of a concept and may occupy an arbitrary number of bytes. For example, character "S" (capital letter 'S') occupies 1 byte whereas character  (kissing lips) occupies 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is wrong. byte is 1 character. a character in binary is a series of 8 on or offs or 0 or 1s. one of those is a bit and 8 bits make a byte so 1 byte is one character.so 2 bytes hold two characters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of the string. 1 byte per character in `ASCII` and  2 bytes per character in `Unicode`. so 2 byte can hold only single Unicode character or 2 ASCII character.

**The following code will explain my answer**

```
MsgBox(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("h")) '<--- displays 2
MsgBox(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("h")) '<--- displays 1
```